# Using Nodejs and Passport-Amazon - getting "We're sorry" error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

When setting up Oath using the Amazon strategy in the NodeJS Passport module, I'm seeing a generic error page when trying to authenticate. The same error occurs whether running it in my app or running the example app from here:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-amazon/tree/master/examples/login

I'm using the correct credentials (client id and secret) from the Amazon's Sellercentral. Has anyone else got this to work?

Answer (score 0):

On further investingation, I found a comment in the source:

```
<!--
Error Code: 400
Error Message: The redirect URI you provided has not been whitelisted for your application
-->
```

After adding the callback URL to the "Allowed return URLs", it now works.